# How appropriate are question-origin tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange, meta-tags

So, we now have the [breaking-bad tag on Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad). The posts there aren't really bad ones, some, like [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/how-does-walter-white-make-pure-crystal-meth-using-a-non-stereospecific-reaction), have really interesting answers. It also might be helping drive traffic to the site.

I've remarked before (in jest), that a [things-I-won't-work-with or derek-lowe](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/why-do-chalcogens-group-vi-stink-so-badly#comment6968_4636) tag would be nice to have to keep track of the questions sprouting from [Derek Lowe's blog series](http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/things_i_wont_work_with/) that has prompted a couple of posts on our site.

Appropriateness of these *specific* tags aside, in general how appropriate are tags that describe *what sparked the question* rather than *what the question is about*?

They seem to be a form of meta tag, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

4 (or less) appropriate (& required) tags + 1 meta-ish tag == +Okay (Good for traffic & some fun)

However, if we have no slot for the 5th tag (more important tag needs to be in place) then the actually necessary tag deserves the 5th slot. The `Breaking Bad` reference can be given as an edit to the question, IMO. (preserving the traffic pull maybe?)

The above is for times when we don't have a heck load of tv-serials linked questions pouring in, in that case we'ld need some different rules. For the time being, I would enjoy such tags being entertained, keeps us human. :)